# Take JSONObject as a parameter in Mockito mock method

Tags: java, json, testing, junit, mockito

I am trying to use Mockito to mock a method for my JUnit testing. The Method takes a JSONObject from simple-json as a parameter and responds with a JSONObject. The method I am tring to mock is from another class and the code I am testing calls it. I can not seem to get Mockito to catch my request and respond accordingly. Am I completely missing something here?

```
public class TestClass{
  JSONObject jsonRequest;
  JSONObject jsonReturn;

  AnotherClass anotherClass = Mockito.mock(AnotherClass.class);

  @Before
  public void setUp(){
    jsonRequest = this.readJSONFromFile("jsonRequest.json");
    jsonReturn = this.readJSONFromFile("jsonReturn.json");
    Mockito.when(anotherClass.anotherClassMethod(jsonRequest)).thenReturn(jsonReturn);
  }

  @Test
  public void testMethod(){
     TestClass testClass = new TestClass();
     assertEquals(testClass.method(jsonRequest), jsonReturn);
  }
}
```

Comment: So i tried to write out an example and have failed. I have now revied and ficed my example to what I actually need:

Answer (score 2):

You're mocking the wrong method signature. You have a mock set up for `method(JSONObject)` but are calling `method(JSONObject, JSONObject)` (note the two arguments). You'll either need to mock the two-argument method, or only call the one-argument method in the test.

I'd also recommend changing the mock to accept any instance of a `JSONObject`:

```
Mockito.when(testClass.method(any(JSONObject.class)).thenReturn(jsonReturn);
```

Finally, as mentioned by Mehmudjan Mehmet, remove the new instance of `TestClass` from your test as otherwise your mocks won't work. You should be using the instance declared at the top of your test.

Answer (score 1):

You mocked the method of the mock object,
but in your test class, instead of using mock object `testClass`,
you instantiated a new TestClass object which won't be intercepted by Mockito.
Plus the last line of your code doesn't look right,

```
assertEquals(testClass.method(jsonRequest, jsonReturn));
```

Ok. Your testMethod should look something like:

```
@Test
public void testMethod(){
   assertEquals(testClass.method(jsonRequest), jsonReturn);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: @JimBob91: I think you are kinda confused about the mocking. Mockito will only catch your requests/methods only if your requests/methods are invoked/issued by the mocks (mock objects). In your code, the only mock object you have is "anotherClass", and you mocked the anotherClassMethod() of it in your `@Before` method, which means Mockito will catch your request, only if you called anotherClass.anotherClassMethod(jsonRequest) method in your `@Test` methods.

Comment: And in your `testMethod()` you are calling `testClass.method(jsonRequest)`, `testClass` is not a mock, and your are not mocking `testClass.method(jsonRequest)` behavior, so Mockito won't catch it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have wrong the assert

```
 assertEquals(testClass.method(jsonRequest), jsonReturn);
```